# Running my own daemon on Heroku, how can I contact it from the Internet?

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

I have a Django application that runs fine on Heroku. At this point, I'd like to start a second process that implements a daemon that exchanges data with other devices and populates the database of the Django app.

I implemented this second daemon as a custom command of a Django app, so in my `Procfile` I have

```
web: gunicorn portal.wsgi --log-file -
listener: python manage.py listen_to_devices
```

At this point I start the daemon with `heroku ps:scale listener=1`.

Devices are not able to connect. While debugging, I noticed that my app has several entries in the DNS, I guess for load balancing:

```
ottavio@debian:~$ nslookup xxx.herokuapp.com
Server:     192.168.69.2
Address:    192.168.69.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   xxx.herokuapp.com
Address: 52.51.85.80
Name:   xxx.herokuapp.com
Address: 52.212.106.249
Name:   xxx.herokuapp.com
Address: 54.171.30.127
Name:   xxx.herokuapp.com
Address: 54.171.254.93
Name:   xxx.herokuapp.com
Address: 54.194.235.52
Name:   xxx.herokuapp.com
Address: 99.80.174.196
Name:   xxx.herokuapp.com
Address: 52.18.173.71
Name:   xxx.herokuapp.com
Address: 52.48.204.199

ottavio@debian:~$
```

So, I guess I am doing something wrong. Port 8080 does not seem to be open whenever I try to telnet to it.

How can I have my devices reach my daemon port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I have my devices reach my daemon port?

You can't.

At least, you can't if you already have another process already listening for web traffic. [Dynos with the `web` type are the only ones that can receive traffic from the internet](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-configurations), and Heroku [only gives you a single `$PORT` to bind to](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#common-runtime-networking).

Depending on what it does you might be able to run your daemon as a separate Heroku app, but generally speaking apps expect to see HTTP traffic.